# How to embed QuickTime VR "thingy" in an HTML page?

Tags: html, quicktime, virtual-reality

Tag this with `send-me-the-codez` if you will. I've been asked to assist in putting a Quicktime VR *thingy* (for lack of better term. movie? applet?) in an HTML page. How would I go about this? Pointers to examples online are most appreciated.

*Note*: I checked out Apple's iPhone 360-degree views, which (I think) are the only examples of QuickTime VR that I've seen on the internets. The Apple specimens are laden with JavaScript and seem like terrible overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware embedding QTVR is just the same as embedding a QT video, eg:

```
<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" width="..." height="...">
    <param name="src" value="....mov">
    <param name="autoplay" value="true">
    <param name="controller" value="true">

    <embed src="....mov" width="..." height="..." autoplay="true" controller="true"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Is the `classid` really meaningful? I googled for this value and found that it tells IE to use a "`Quicktime ActiveX control`". What about other browsers? Is this value universal across all of them?

Comment: No, other browsers will use the `embed` instead. Ideally both the object-with-classid and the embed should be replaced by a single, standards-compliant object-with-type element, but this has not historically been well-supported by IE. I haven't tried for QT, but certainly with Flash it has the problem of not being able to begin playing a partially-downloaded file.